# Can we declare member variable of JPA static metamodel class as a final?

Tags: java, jpa, sonarqube

I have a JPA static metamodel class which is as follows-

```
@StaticMetamodel(Test.class)
public class Test_{
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Test, String> id;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Test, String> name;
    public static volatile SingularAttribute<Test, String> description;
    public static volatile ListAttribute<Test, Property> property;
}
```

I am using `sonarqube` to improve my code quality and it suggested that I have to change **public static id to field final** for above member variables.

Can anyone suggest that should I change these variables to final?

Comment: You should configure sonarqube to ignore automatically-generated code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `JPA` static metamodel ("_") classes are generated by your `JPA` provider, not by you. They follow exactly what the JPA spec says to include (and there is no "final" there). Not including "final" makes perfect sense because those variables need initialising, and are not initialised by included code.